# Redirect to subdomain in rails with URL params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redirect, request, subdomain

My site has different languages. Each language has its own subdomain. I'm able to redirect the users correctly to the appropriate subdomain and URL path. However, I haven't found a way to preserve the URL parameters. I use Rails 2.3. My current redirect looks like this:

```
redirect_to('http://' + I18n.locale.to_s + '.' + request.domain + request.path)
```

How do I add the URL parameters to that or how can it be rewritten to preserve the URL parameters if there are any.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it this way:

```
  split_url = request.url.partition(request.domain)
  redirect_to('http://' + I18n.locale.to_s + '.' + split_url[1] + split_url[2])
```

Comment: This works, but to make the code work with both http and https use request.protocol instead of 'http://'.

Answer (score 0):

See the Rails Guide http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html, chapter 2.5.
You don't have to recreate manually the URL.

Comment: I use the method in the guide to detect the locale if the user is already on the subdomain. The urls are then all handled by rails as you say. My problem is if the user wants to switch locale (click on a flag icon for example) or if the user is coming from a link that doesn't include the locale in the subdomain. Then it needs to be redirected to the correct subdomain. My site was not translated before. Not sure my answer I just posted is the best way, but it works.